What equipment is needed to replace multiple AC adapters with a unit that plugs into a single plug?
I'd like to replace 3 different AC adapters with a single wall unit like this one that plugs into a single outlet and has 3 USB-C ports. From that, I'd run:

USB-C to 12V barrel jack cable to a TP-link AX1800 router whose current AC adapter is specced at 12v, 1.5A DC
USB-C to 12V barrel jack cable to an Arris Surfboard modem whose current AC adapter is specced at 12v, 2.5A DC (using it in bridge mode since its router capability is no longer working reliably, hence the need for the separate router)
Standard USB-C to USB-C cable to Orange Pi Zero 3 microcomputer whose standard power supply is rated at 5V, 3A, but apparently can be run at 2A when running headless

Will the linked products be able to produce enough power - particularly for the 12V 2.5A? I'm confused on the wall unit since it shows 25W / 67W max, and I'm not sure what the difference is between the numerator and denominator there.

This is a decent question for the Hardware Recommendations SE site.
